# In the Google Actions console, is there a way to see connection errors?

Tags: actions-on-google

We have over a thousand users connected and using our Google home actions, but randomly we'll have a user who can't connect. I've been looking through the action console and I can see logs for people using the actions, but I haven't been able to find connection/initial integration logs. Is there anywhere I can see those?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by being unable to connect?

Comment: @NickFelker The main issue I've seen is successfully connecting with Google (that is, we've completed the handshake and have a token), but Google doesn't show the connection on their end

Comment: Does it work in the [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)